# Magnific Popup AutoLoad on Page Loading... Not Working

Tags: magnific-popup

I installed this code on a single page PHP page and it works the way I want it to. Problem is page I need to install it on is broken up into 4 PHP pages.(Home.php, which also includes, Header, Menu, and Footer PHP pages...)  and I can't get the code to work. I've tried installing it different places but no luck... if anyone can help would be much appreciated... Code is below.

page to install on is: http://tonysatthejhouse.com THANKS!!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tonysatthejhouse.com/superadmin/assets/css/Mag3.css" />


</head>

<body>

<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>

<script data-require="jquery@1.9.1" data-semver="1.9.1" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
 <script src="http://tonysatthejhouse.com/superadmin/assets/js/MagJS4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



$(document).ready(function() {
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: 'http://tonysatthejhouse.com/superadmin/assets/extraimages/Restaurant_Week AD-01.jpg', //      can be a HTML string, jQuery object, or CSS selector
      type: 'image'
    }
  });
})

.white-popup {
  width:500px;
  height:700px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:10px;
  background:white;
  border:2px solid black;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
   border-radius: 3px;
    }
```